# PayPal recurring payment "add-ons"

Tags: php, paypal, recurring

Requirement:

We want to have a base subscription which is X/month, done via recurring payments, and give clients the ability to choose extra "add-ons" as they please. An "add-on" will be Y/Month and should last the remainder of the base subscription. For example, the base subscription is 10/month and feature X is extra 5/month and feature Y is an extra 7/month. I choose to have the base subscription with feature X and Y so my total monthly payment for a year will be 22/month. Now, if I chose only the base subscription for the first 6 months and want to start using feature X for the final 6 months of my subscription, the final 6 months should be 15/month opposed to the previous 10/month. In further terms, add-on features subscription should last the duration of the base subscription.

Is there a simple way to do this via the PayPal API?

Answer (score 0):

Actual recurring payments profiles (setup with Standard or Express Checkout) have a limit on how much you can raise the amount of a profile.  You can only raise it by 20% every 180 days.  If you create a recurring payments profile with Payments Pro, though, then there is no such limit and you can change the amount at any time to whatever you need.  I wouldn't recommend going without EC, though, as lots of people prefer to pay with PayPal.

What you could do, though, instead of using the recurring payments APIs would be to use billing agreements / reference transactions.  This way you'd save the billing agreement / auth ID in your database and then you can use the DoReferenceTransaction API to process any variable amount you need to at any time.

So in that case you would basically be building your own recurring payments system where you'll save the "next payment date" in your database, and then you'll have an automated script run each day to process all of the payments that are due that day via a reference transaction.

Reference transactions work with Payments Pro, too, so if you're using that everything would still work the same.

Since you're working with PHP I'd recommend taking a look at my [class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  It will make all of these API calls very simple for you.